# Extract FileName from getAbsolutePath() method

Tags: java

I'm using a method from this site to read all the files exist on the system hard drives, it's working fine, but i need to check that a certain file exists while searching.
to make the story short here is the line code which is reading the files

parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());

how can I assign the output from this method to a string so i can search iniside this string for the file I want, or there any way to add/change to this statement to get the filename directely in a string?

```
 public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory){   
  File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles();  
   if(filesInDirectory != null){  
        for(File f : filesInDirectory){   
            if(f.isDirectory()){   
               parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());  // get full path 

            }   
            System.out.println("Current File -> " + f);             
        }        
   }

}
```

Comment: If you search for a specific file name, why don't you check before `if(f.isDirectory())`? The method `f.getName()` returns the file name

Comment: Pass either a `File` object or a `Path` in your recursive call, not a `String`. Then you have easy access to the file name. And you can always have a method accepting a `String` as wrapper around the first call if needed.

Comment: f.getName() is returning the dir rather than the file name, don't know why

Comment: For your goal, it looks like thr FileVisitor is the best solution:

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to write a simple a method that prints the paths or if you just want to find a file recursively. I that case, putting in the else clause of the `if(f.isDirectory())` a `if (f.getName().compareTo(fileName) == 0)` I think will do the job (when it is not a directory, it's a file). I think this is what @XtremeBaumer wrote before. Then, you can return a true, or print a message or whatever your needs are (return an array of strings, if multiple files have the same name, but are in different paths).

Answer (score 0):

Use objects rather than strings since they tend to offer useful functionality that strings don’t offer. In your case pass a `File` object or a `Path` object to your recursive method. I take it that you start out from a string, so have your public method accept a string and construct the first object.

```
public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory) {
    parseAllFiles(new File(parentDirectory));
}

private static void parseAllFiles(File dir) {
    File[] filesInDirectory = dir.listFiles();
    if (filesInDirectory != null) {
        for (File f : filesInDirectory) {
            String fileName = f.getName();
            String fullPathName = f.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Current File -> " + fileName);
            System.out.println("Current path -> " + fullPathName);

            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                parseAllFiles(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn’t get whether you wanted only the file name or the full path name of the file, but the code shows how to extract each into a string. You may then search inside these two strings for whatever you are looking for.

**java.nio since Java 7**

I routinely use `java.nio.file` for file system operations. For everyday purposes I don’t find it better to work with than the older `File` class, but it does offer a wealth of options that the older class doesn’t offer. @Shahar Rotshtein in a comment mentioned the `FileVisitor` interface from `java.nio.file`. Depending on your exact requirements `Files.walkFileTree` passing your own `FileVisitor` may be the best option for you. I have not understood your real requirements well enough to offer a code example.

**Links**

- [`java.nio.file` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)
- Section [Walking the file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) in the Oracle tutorial: Basic I/O